# JavaFX CSS being applied on all ScrollPanes

Tags: java, css, javafx

Excuse my English, I am trying to create a JavaFX application that has two ScrollPanes. Now, I want one with rounded corners and one with flat. I am using FXML to create the scene and styling with CSS.

My CSS (what I've done so far...):

```
.scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb,
.scroll-bar:vertical .thumb {
    -fx-background-color : #dddddd;
    -fx-background-insets : 2.0, 0.0, 0.0;
    -fx-background-radius : 0em;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb:hover,
.scroll-bar:vertical .thumb:hover {
    -fx-background-color : #9e9e9e;
    -fx-background-insets : 2.0, 0.0, 0.0;
    -fx-background-radius : 0em;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb,
.scroll-bar:vertical .thumb {
    -fx-background-color : #dddddd;
    -fx-background-insets : 2.0, 0.0, 0.0;
    -fx-background-radius : 2em;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb:hover,
.scroll-bar:vertical .thumb:hover {
    -fx-background-color : #9e9e9e;
    -fx-background-insets : 2.0, 0.0, 0.0;
    -fx-background-radius : 2em;
}
```

I know (and confirmed) that both scroll-bar thumbs will appear rounded, I am pulling my hair out now (one-by-one). How can I somehow make two different scroll-bar styles in the same `CSS` and assign each ScrollPane in the FXML a different one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a CSS class to one of the ScrollPane and then write a different CSS style to that class.

Adding CSS class from FXML:

```
<ScrollPane styleClass="rounded-scroll-pane">
```

Adding CSS class from code:

```
someScrollPane.getStyleClass().add("rounded-scroll-pane");
```

And then apply to CSS file:

```
// General scroll style
.scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb,
.scroll-bar:vertical .thumb {
    -fx-background-color : #dddddd;
    -fx-background-insets : 2.0, 0.0, 0.0;
    -fx-background-radius : 0em;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb:hover,
.scroll-bar:vertical .thumb:hover {
    -fx-background-color : #9e9e9e;
    -fx-background-insets : 2.0, 0.0, 0.0;
    -fx-background-radius : 0em;
}

// Custom ScrollPane style
.rounded-scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb,
.rounded-scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:vertical .thumb {
    -fx-background-color : #dddddd;
    -fx-background-insets : 2.0, 0.0, 0.0;
    -fx-background-radius : 2em;
}

.rounded-scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb:hover,
.rounded-scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:vertical .thumb:hover {
    -fx-background-color : #9e9e9e;
    -fx-background-insets : 2.0, 0.0, 0.0;
    -fx-background-radius : 2em;
}
```